# How much of my dexterity modifier can I add when wearing scale mail?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class

In the 5th edition of Dungeons & Dragons scale mail armor has an AC of 14 + Dexterity bonus (max 2). Does this mean that I can only add 2 from my Dexterity modifier even if it is higher?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to how we do things around here. In particular, we generally look for expert questions and answers that will stand the test of time. In order to improve the quality of this question, I'd recommend getting more specific about what research you've done on your own and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 18):

That is exactly what it means.

> If you wear medium
>   armor, you add your Dexterity modifier, to a maximum
>   of +2, to the base number from your armor type to
>   determine your Armor Class.

PHB p.144

Answer (score 3):

yes, if it says max dex bonus is +2 that means you can only add 2 extra ac from your dex, it's meant to imply the armor slows you by it being so heavy, so you cant dodge and move as easy